# Python setup.py - Command not being installed when running setup.py manually

Tags: python, pip, setuptools, packaging, setup.py

I have a pip package, and it installs a command line tool and so you can use it anywhere in the terminal like `name args`, but when i do manual installation with `python setup.py install`, it doesn't install that command, I can use the module inside the python script and import it, but I cannot use the command, my directory structure-

```
wand-cli
├── setup.py
├── wand
├── wandbox
│   ├── colorschemes
│   │     ...
│   ├── commands
│   │     ...
│   └── utilities
        ...
```

I am using this in setup.py, `scripts=["wand"]`
So what can I do to have the command installed on running setup.py manually?

Answer (score 2):

Alright did a bit of research, thanks to python's docs, i just need to provide the `user` option

```
python setup.py install --user
```